# Multiple find and replace in a word document

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, find-and-replace, libreoffice-writer

I want to do a series of find and replace operations. Unfortunately, the documents I have to work on are in Word (.docx) format so I cannot script this. These are book chapters so formatting is important (italics, bold, indentation, fonts), I cannot simply convert to plain text.

Say I have a list of (about 20 different) words as follows:

```
black
blue
yellow
```

The replacement I need to do is to add accents so I would have a list of replacements like this:

```
bláck
blúe
yéllow
```

Is there a way I can automate this in Word? I would be happy to use another piece of software. I would be even happier if I could do this on Linux using scripting tools (but I guess this is wishful thinking). I have access to Linux and Windows systems, MS Word and LibreOffice.

Comment: seems like [this](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/word/5485-word-multiple-find-and-replace.html) interactive macro works well for me.. hope it can be a useful alternative. ( :

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found [this thread](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=227122) in which a macro that does more or less what you need is suggested. Perhaps that will help.

Comment: @terdon Thanks for the edit. That's far more simple. I would like to talk to you some time.